# In an Oracle database query, is there any way to acquire a shared row lock inside of a transaction?

Tags: oracle

Is there any way to acquire a shared row lock inside of a transaction?

I realize that `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` can be used to get a exclusive row lock (that would cause UPDATEs and SELECTs to block till the transaction ends), but is there any equivalent that can be used to get a shared row lock (that would cause `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` queries to block, but other attempts to acquire the same shared row lock would not block)?

Comment: Oracle writers don't block readers so a `select for update` wouldn't block a `select`.  Unless both are actually doing a `select for update` of course.

Comment: I'm actually trying to do exactly that.  I'd like to acquire a lock manually that will cause a separate `SELECT...FOR UPDATE` to block till the first transaction is complete.  I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Then I'm not sure I follow.  A `select for update` will acquire a lock that blocks another session from doing an `update` or a `select for update`.  It will not block another session from doing a `select`.  That appears to be what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'd like to get a *shared* lock that blocks an `UPDATE` or a  `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, but won't block other transactions from getting a shared lock.on the same row.  As opposed to an exclusive row lock, which is what  `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` gives me.

Comment: Rather than doing a `select for update`, you could potentially use the `dbms_lock` package to get a custom lock (name it, say, 'tableName_pkValue' so 'emp_12345' for pk 12345 in the emp table) and then request whatever mode you want.  Of course, that means that your code would need to manage the locking itself-- an application that didn't know about your custom lock could run an update on the table without respecting your custom lock.  If that's not what you want, can you explain the business problem you're solving in more detail?

Comment: [This other question gets at my actual scenario more directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66910953/in-an-oracle-database-query-is-there-any-way-to-block-when-an-uncommitted-row-h), but here I'd just like to know if there is a way to acquire a RS lock on a row, just like `SELECT ...FOR UPDATE` gives me an RX lock.

Comment: On a row in a user table, no.  On a custom lock object, yes (which may be acquiring a RS lock on a row in an Oracle table somewhere under the covers).