# In an Oracle database query, is there any way to block when an uncommitted row has been INSERTed?

Tags: oracle

In an Oracle database, is there any way for a query to be blocked when an uncommitted row has been INSERTed?

Suppose I want to get all rows in a table that match my WHERE clause, but there is an uncommitted row that has been inserted that might match it.  I want my query to be blocked till the inserted row's transaction completes. Ordinary SELECTs, of course, only return the committed data. Is there a way to be blocked and thus wait for the recently-inserted row (which presumably has an exclusive row lock on it)?

I was thinking that perhaps, before my INSERT, I might acquire a shared lock on some other row in another table, then as part of the query in question, try to SELECT the desired data FOR UPDATE, even though I don't intend to update it.  If this is a viable approach, any ideas how to acquire this shared lock?

Is there any easier way than that?

Comment: Can you explain the use case?  Potentially you could accomplish this using `dbms_lock` and custom locks that that `insert` transaction takes out and the `select` transaction checks.  But I would tend to suspect there is a more robust way to accomplish whatever you're trying to accomplish.  Presumably, if you have a consumer process, that consumer is going to need to run repeatedly so I'm not sure why you'd want to wait on an uncommitted transaction when you can just pick it up on the next run using, say, Oracle AQ.

Comment: I have a table that uses an IDENTITY column that must only increase.  It has happened that one process INSERTs a row (say with ID 1234) but does not commit, then another process INSERTS a row, which gets a larger ID (say 1235) and commits, then the first process commits later.  During that time I process data out of that table and I SELECT a row 1235 but no 1234.  My consuming process then saves that I have completed all through 1235 and 1234 is never picked up. Instead I'd like to block the query till all rows being inserted are committed or rolled back.

Comment: Why not use something like Oracle AQ to guarantee delivery of the messages to the consumer process?  Does something break if 1235 is processed before 1234 if 1235 commits before 1234?  If you really want to ensure that 1235 can't commit until 1234 either commits or rolls back, you could use the old school custom sequence generator (i.e. create a `sequence_table`, select a row for update to generate the next value).  That'll serialize the `insert` transactions so that only one is active at a time.  That produces a serious hit to the scalability of the insert process of course

Comment: I agree that prohibiting inserts for the duration of a transaction seems untenable, which is why I was hoping there would be a wait to just block certain queries instead based on the uncommitted row.  Never used AQ before.  I'll look into it.

Comment: You can also consider using [ora_rowscn](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ORA_ROWSCN-Pseudocolumn.html#GUID-8071AAB0-F656-4C93-B926-0BCE1439F121) for figuring out which rows to process.

Comment: Sounds like you need [Continuous Query Notification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adfns/cqn.html#GUID-373BAF72-3E63-42FE-8BEA-8A2AEFBF1C35).

Comment: The below link might be helpful. Provided with two ways flashback, and ora_rowscn.
 (https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:454580500346047540)